# Scrolling two UITableViews simultaneously

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have one, parent "ListViewController" with mainTable and menuTable declaration.
I've got also two controllers "MenuController" and "MainController" that implements "ListViewController". Each with its own storyboard, but thanks to ECSlidingViewController (facebook menu effect) I can see both on the one screen.  MenuController has menuTable , MainController has mainTable. I want mainTable to be scrolled together with menuTable.
The problem is that in `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` in "ListViewController" I can set ONLY contentOffset of table which is currently scrolled.

**ListViewController.h**

```
@interface ListViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITableView *mainTable;
IBOutlet UITableView *menuTable;
}
```

**ListViewController.m**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
self.mainTable.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;;
// works only when I am scrolling mainTable, 
// but I need it when I am scrolling menuTable

}
```

**MenuController.m**

```
@interface MenuController :  ListViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
...
}
```

**MainController.m**

```
@interface MainController :  ListViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need only compare `scrollView` with `self.mainTable` or `self.menuTable` in `scrollViewDidScroll `.

Answer (score 1):

As I see `ListViewController` is delegate of one table so `scrollViewDidScroll:` was called only for this UITableView. You should track second table scrolling in it delegate, you can make a proxy delegate between table and its real delegate ...

```
@interface ProxyTableViewDelegate <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<UITableViewDelegate> realDelegate;
- (instancetype)initWithRealDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)realDelegate;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

@end

@implementation ProxyTableViewDelegate

- (instancetype)initWithRealDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)realDelegate
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.realDelegate = realDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Custom actions ...

    if ([self.realDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)])
        [self.realDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:self.realDelegate];
}

@end
```

usage:

```
// tableView.delegate != nil
tableView.delegate = [[ProxyTableViewDelegate alloc] initWithRealDelegate:tableView.delegate];
```

Comment: I'm a newbie, and I can't handle with this :/ Could you give me some extra details related to my example?

Comment: Where Should I put this code, and how to make it works together? Thanks!

Comment: This was a fantastically useful response! Thank you.